# graphql mutate object with empty string values

Tags: graphql, apollo, mutation, vue-apollo

I'm trying to mutate a graphql query using `vue-apollo`

```js
let fields = [
  { name: 'A', value: '0' },
  { name: 'B', value: '' }
]
this.$apollo
  .mutate({
    mutation: gql`
      mutation($serve: Int!, $fields: [ComponentInput]) {
        visitCreate(serve: $serve, fields: $fields) {
          id
          ...
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      serve: this.serve.id,
      fields: fields
    }
  })
```

But got the following error:

```
Variable "$fields" got invalid value [{"name":"A","value":"0"},{"name":"B","value":null}]; Expected non-nullable type String! not to be null at value[1].value
```

actually the `fields` should be `[{"name":"A","value":"0"},{"name":"B","value":""}]` and I don't know how.

Also I've tried `JSON.stringify(fields)`

[image]

any help please

Comment: I'm not sure but in the docs  it is: `name: String! value: String!` @DanielRearden

Comment: This actually may be a bug with the client. If the field is `String`, an empty string shouldn't get coerced into null on the server side. If you look at the outgoing request in the network tab of your browser's dev tools, I'm guessing the value being sent is actually `null`, right?

Comment: yes it is and the problem is this. the empty string turns to null and the result in network tab is `{name: "A", value: null}`

Comment: Oh no it isn't, i'll put a screenshot

Comment: Ok, so the issue is not with `vue-apollo` or `apollo-client`. The data is being sent over correctly. Could be a bug with whatever GraphQL implementation the server is running. It looks like the empty string is getting coerced into a null, which shouldn't happen. I tested this with GraphQL.js and I get the expected result (empty string is passed to resolver, no error). Based on the error, that *looks* like `graphql-php` but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielRearden, I shared this problem with backend developer and waiting for response. actually I just wanted to make sure it isn't  my mistake